# Better way to test .animate with qUnit

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, tdd, qunit

Getting to know TDD i wrote a simple test suit for moving `dom` elements to the left.

I testing animations I need to wait for them to finish. I didn't want to use promises since it feels like monkey patching and I ended up using qUnit example form:

```
test("move 50", function () {
   //Creates an element for testing and attaches to document
   var el = appendToTest(); 
   ok(el.css('left') == "auto", "element 0");
   stop();
   moveLeft(el, 50, 100);
   setTimeout(function () {
     equal(el.css("left"), "50px");
     start();
  }, 101);//Timeout duration
});
```

**[full fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raam86/25u3k/3/)**

The test fails on all jQuery versions but `2.x (edge)`

```
failed
Expected:   
"50px"
Result:     
"49.69220733642578px"
Diff:   
"50px" "49.69220733642578px"
```

Incrementing the timeout duration enough makes the test pass so I figured the animation didn't finish before being probed for the left property.

But this doesn't seem right. Having to *guess* how long to wait.
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restructure your test and also the method `moveLeft`. What you are currently doing is invoking `.animate` (I presume, `moveLeft` is a wrapper around `.animate`) and then telling qUnit to wait for 101 ms before checking the element's left position. As you've already noted, this is not a very reliable way to test!

Instead, you need to take advantage of the ability of `.animate` to invoke a *callback function* when it's finished executing; so that you modify your `moveLeft` function to accept this callback, which you define as

```
function() {equal(el.css("left"), "50px");start();}
```

and you pass *this* callback to `.animate` within your `moveLeft` function

e.g your call now looks like this:

```
//tells qUnit to expect that one assertion will happen.
//this will mean that your test will also fail if moveLeft doesn't invoke the callback.
      expect(1); 
//define the calback function
      var callback = function(){equal(el.css("left"), "50px");start();}
//execute the test:
       moveLeft(el, 50, 100,callback);
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raam86/25u3k/5/)

And as a bonus, you now have a much more flexible `moveLeft` function that can accept any arbitrary callback. \o/

Comment: Thank you! This is a very nice way. If you have some resources you can share I will be great.

Comment: I'd recommend having a good read of the qUnit test intro http://qunitjs.com/intro/ and also check out "The Art of Unit Testing" (done for C# but the principles are the same - it's basically the unit testing bible...) and also "Testable Javascript"  -  both excellent books for getting into the unit testing mindset.

Comment: @raam86 excellent idea with the jsfiddle!
Hopefully someone else will find this useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's a better way to do it - use Sinon's fake timers - http://sinonjs.org/docs/#clock

1. In setup initialise fake timers:

   `setup: function () {
       this.clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
   }`
2. After calling `moveLeft()` function in your test, set fake timer to 100 ms:

   `this.clock.tick(100);`
3. Now you can test animation result right away without using async test:

   `equal(el.css("left"), "50px");`